# Unmount Vue inistance or remount in a new location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, templates, vue.js

I am working on a project where a new feature is to be added. The feature uses a Vue instance that was created to live on one page. It grabs: `window.location.href` and creates meta data with some other info that can be shared to other users.

This now needs to have same share feature to live on a page that is dynamically created. I have several rows of information, each row (can be one row, can be 100 rows) has one dropdown that is populated with the info from the box that is clicked on. Within the dropdown, I need to have this share feature. I am able to get the first row to populate with the Vue instance with a `shareWidget.$mount('some selector[with a data attribute="active"')`
 function. This works great no matter which row I click first.

The problem is that, as soon as I click on another row (`$('some selector'`) is removed and a new `$('some selector[with a data attribute="active"')`) is added within the dropdown that is now part of the active row.

I cannot get the new selector to be populated with the Vue instance called sharingWidget. I have tried to destroy and mount again, but I get `[Vue warn]: $mount() should be called only once.` which is expected. Is there a way to make the Vue instance move to a new location or unmount then mount it again?

Comment: I did something similar recently. What I ended up doing was saving my data in in a Vuex store. Then I destroyed the old instance, and remount a _new_ instance with the same data as but a different location as the the previous one.

Depending how large and complex your app is, this may or may not be possible.

You could save the data all in a Vuex store, then cache that data in a global variable. Vuex has a `replaceState` method, which you could use to reseed the data.

Comment: If you can provide some basic code or a gist, I can take a look and maybe give you some ideas.

Comment: For those coming across this with Vue 3, would be worth looking at changing the `:key` and if you run into issues mounting multiple instances of the name component, ensure the 'name' attribute on the component is different. Info on `:key` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466574/339803

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this can actually be done. Once a Vue instance is mounted, it cannot be mounted again. The Vue instance, as opposed to a component can only live in one place. My work around was that instead of each row having a drop down, only one ever exists. When I tile is clicked on, it gets the active row and appends the drop down to the bottom of it. So, as I said, unmounting and remounting do not seem to be a thing.