# How to re-mount a component in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component which is mounted as part of the DOM rendering. The skeleton of the application is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <my-component></my-component>
      <button>press this button to reload the component</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`<my-component>` is functional (it displays a few form inputs) and `$emit` data to the parent.

**Is there a way to re-mount it?** The goal is to have a component content and setup as if it was just rendered for the first time (including a reset of the `data()` elements which hold its state).

There are [some solutions](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/702) to that but they all assume a rewrite of `data()`, which I would like to avoid.

My understanding is that a component is actuall HTML/CSS/JS code injected in the dom in the right place during the rendering so I fear that the concept of "re-mounting" it does not exist - I just wanted to make sure before going the data()-rewrite way.

Comment: why you want to avoid reseting `data`?

Comment: @mklimek: I was looking for a cleaner way to reset components. If I overwrite `data()`, I need to keep the original on the side, or have a "master copy" of it (empty), or other stuff like that. I was hoping for re-mount command which would just reset it to its generic state. This is not the end of the world if there is no - it is rather a matter of aesthetics for me (and code simplicity).

Comment: Data can be reset (to the original returned by the `data()` function) with this handy one-liner:  `Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this));`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

## The trick is to alter the key

When the key changes, vue regards it as a new component, so it will unmount the "old" component, and mount a "new" component.

See example, the `created()` hook will only run once, so if you see the value change, you're seeing a brand new object.

example:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<div>{{ rand }}</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      remount: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.remount = !this.remount; // true▶false▶true▶false...
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    componentKey:0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component :key="componentKey"></my-component>
  <button @click="componentKey=!componentKey">press this button to reload the component</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is excellent. This also fits perfectly with my intended use where I need some sore of id for the component (passed as a prop). I read here and there about `key` in components, this is an opportunity to learn more. Thanks again!

Comment: Good Example. i am also trying to achieve what you have. i have component inside tab-bar. i am getting below error
```Attribute ":key" is ignored on component <> because the component is a fragment instance```
can you help?

Comment: can you ask a separate question for this?

Comment: This won't remount it. It will only re-render the view.

Comment: @Roel Well, the mounted and destroyed methods are running correctly when you do this, so it seems to be a re-mount.

Answer (score 13):

In your template you'll add the v-if directive:

```
<template>
  <my-component v-if="renderComponent" />
</template>
```

In your script you'll add in this method that uses nextTick:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        renderComponent: true,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      forceRerender() {
        // Remove my-component from the DOM
        this.renderComponent = false;

        this.$nextTick(() => {
          // Add the component back in
          this.renderComponent = true;
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

This is what's going on here:

> Initially renderComponent is set to true, so my-component is rendered
> When we call forceRerender we immediately set renderComponent to false
> We stop rendering my-component because the v-if directive now evaluates to false
> On the next tick renderComponent is set back to true
> Now the v-if directive evaluates to true, so we start rendering my-component again

Comment: good for me great