# Implementing a v-loading directive, where content is replaced while data is loading

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, directive

I'm trying to implement a `v-loading` directive in Vue, where the content of the element is replaced by a spinner while the expression evalutes to true.

It would be used like this:

```
<div v-loading="loading">
  <p v-if="!data"> No data </p>
  <p v-else>Here is the data: {{data}}</p>
</div>
```

And here is my implementation (typescript):

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.directive('loading', {
  bind(el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: any) {
    console.log(vnode);
    // console.log(this, arguments);
    vnode.data.html = el.innerHTML;
    vnode.data.loading = binding.value;

    if (binding.value) {
      el.innerHTML = `<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i>`;
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = vnode.data.html;
    }
  },

  update(el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: any, oldVnode: any) {
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
    // console.log("update", this, arguments);

    if (binding.value) {
      el.innerHTML = `<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i>`;
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = oldVnode.data.html;
    }

    vnode.data.html = oldVnode.data.html;
    vnode.data.loading = binding.value;
  }
});
```

It works somewhat, but the html rendered is the html of the element when it was created. All the dynamic rendering is lost.

Instead of the directive, I could create a `v-loading` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot v-if="!loading"></slot>
    <i v-else class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I would rather have the directive. Unfortunately, my knowledge of the vue framework and vnodes is not enough, and the doc from the API on vnodes redirects to [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js), with not a lot of information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Vue instance Life cycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), your directive destroyed the `el`, so it will not render correctly unless `re-mount`(compile the template again).

Below are two solution:

Solution 1: You can append one element to display the spinner then hide its other children.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let vMyDirective = {}
vMyDirective.install = function install (_Vue) {
  let _uid = 'vue-directive-loading' + Date.now().toString('16')
  _Vue.directive('loading', {
    inserted: function (el, binding) {
      let spinner = document.createElement('span')
      spinner.id = _uid
      spinner.innerHTML = 'Loading...'
      spinner.style.display = binding.value ? 'block' : 'none'
      spinner.style['background-color'] = 'red'
      spinner.left = 0
      spinner.top = 0
      spinner.style.position = 'absolute'
      el.childNodes.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.display = binding.value ? 'none' : ''
      })
      el.appendChild(spinner)
    },
    update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      let spinner = document.getElementById(_uid)
      spinner.style.display = binding.value ? 'block' : 'none'
      el.childNodes.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.id === _uid) return
        item.style.display = binding.value ? 'none' : ''
      })
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(vMyDirective)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      dataset: ''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleLoading: function() {
      this.loading = !this.loading
    },
    AddData: function () {
      this.dataset = this.dataset + 'a'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="toggleLoading()">Toggle Loading {{loading}}</button>
  <button v-on:click="AddData()">Add Data</button>
  <div v-loading="loading">
    <p v-if="!dataset"> No data </p>
    <p v-else>Here is the data: {{dataset}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution 2: force update(& force re-mount with new vnode.key) when `loading === false`, but it may not be one good approach since there are warnings against **modifying vnode**.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let vMyDirective = {}
vMyDirective.install = function install (_Vue) {
  _Vue.directive('loading', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      if(binding.value) {
        el.innerHTML = '<span style="background-color:red;top:0;left;0">loading...</span>'
      }
    },
    update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      if(binding.value) {
        el.innerHTML = '<span style="background-color:red;top:0;left;0">loading...</span>'
      } else {
        vnode.key += '1'
        vnode.context.$forceUpdate()
      }
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(vMyDirective)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      dataset: ''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleLoading: function() {
      this.loading = !this.loading
    },
    AddData: function () {
      this.dataset = this.dataset + 'a'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="toggleLoading()">Toggle Loading {{loading}}</button>
  <button v-on:click="AddData()">Add Data</button>
  <div v-loading="loading">
    <p v-if="!dataset"> No data </p>
    <p v-else>Here is the data: {{dataset}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this complete answer! Just a question: why change vnode.key, and where are the warnings against modifying vnode?

Comment: @coyotte508 when key is changed([Vue Guide: list ->key](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) or [how to remount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459837/how-to-re-mount-a-component)), Vue will re-mount it. then for 2nd question, check [Vue Guide: custom directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments), `Apart from el, you should treat these arguments as read-only and never modify them. If you need to share information across hooks, it is recommended to do so through element’s dataset.`

Comment: @coyotte508 you can add `console.log('something')` into the hook='update' and 'bind', you will find once key is changed in hook='update', it will bind again. if comment out `vnode.key += '1'`, it will only trigger hook='update'.