# VueJs - Calling methods passed to dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, datatables, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vuejs component, i'm populating a datatable dynamically

i.e. inside my `methods`:

```
displayUserTypes(){
   axios.get('/antenna-monitor/pull-user-types').then( ({data}) => 
   {
      for(var i in data)
      {
          $('#user-roles').dataTable().fnAddData( [
              data[i].name,
              data[i].description,
              '<a href="#" title="Edit" @click.prevent="editModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> | <a href="#" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'
           ]);
      }

},
created() {
        this.displayUserTypes();         
}
```

This is the HTML part of the component:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @click="addModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New</button>                     
<table id="user-roles" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
 </table>
```

Notice in my `displayUserTypes` function, when populating the datatable, i append an Edit anchor tag and in it, pass the method `editModal`. Clicking on this edit link should fire off a modal as shown below:

in my methods:

```
addModal(){
       $('#userRolesModal').modal('show');
},

editModal(){
       $('#userRolesModal').modal('show');                
},
```

But the modal is not being triggered from the `editModal` function. I've confirmed that the modal is working well since my button for adding that calls the `addModal` function fires the modal. So my thinking is since i call the `editModal` function from a dynamically created link, there's perhaps something extra that i need to pass to my code to trigger this method?

Comment: Hey, are the methods from the component, or are they in the parent vue ?

Comment: hi @LoïcMonard. they're in the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending html dynamically using datatables, vue doesn't listen on dynamic DOM manipulations. So the methods you have defined are not available for the newly inserted HTML.

One way to achieve what you want is to create a new Vue instance with the method editModal and mount it on the table after rendering is done.

```
displayUserTypes() {
  axios.get('/antenna-monitor/pull-user-types').then(({ data }) => {
    for (var i in data) {
      $('#user-roles').dataTable().fnAddData([
        data[i].name,
        data[i].description,
        '<a href="#" title="Edit" @click.prevent="editModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> | <a href="#" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'
      ]);
    }

    new Vue({
     methods: {
        editModal() {
          $('#userRolesModal').modal('show');
        }
     }
    }).$mount('#user-roles')
  });
}
```

If you want to achieve this without creating new vue instance everytime, refer below on how to re-mount a vue component

[How to re-mount a component in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459837/how-to-re-mount-a-component?rq=1)

[Force updating vue component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate)

Comment: Thanks for your input. went with the creating a new Vue instance option. will look at the other options in depth. so essentially, for the solution, does creating a new Vue instance make Vue listen for the DOM manipulation as it happens? and does this option have any drawbacks?

Comment: No it doesnt make vue listen for the DOM manipulation, whenever you say mount this DOM element with this vue instance, vue searches for vue directives inside the element and evaluates them, its a one time action. So what we are essentially doing here is dynamically inserting HTML that contains vue directives and asking vue to evaluate those directives. The new instance is just to force the vue to re-evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your `VueJS` object:

```
var MyObj = new Vue({
    ...
    methods: {
        call_me() {
            alert('Here I am!');
        },
    }
});
```

In your `dynamic HTML` you can generate the following:

```
...
var link = "<a href='#' onclick='JavaScript:MyObj.call_me()'>Click me!</a>";
...
```

I dont know if it is a good solution, but it works.