# Destroying and re-rendering DataTable using html table populated by VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables

I am getting data from a database using Ajax and I display them in an HTML table using VueJS. I let the user perform some actions on the data (Add a new row, edit, delete). It works just fine.

My problem is that I'd like to put a DataTable to allow the user to perform researches and to sort the rows in the table. I'm simply doing : $('my-table').DataTable(); on the HTML table already displayed by Vue. It works until I want to make a change in my data. They're changed in the Vue instance but not rendered in the DataTable.

For now I tried to use the destroy() method on my DataTable then to remake and instance and I have a strange result, here's my code when I want to update my DataTable:

```
 $('my-table').DataTable().destroy();
 // Here I'm getting the data and put it in the Vue instance
 // Once it's done I simply re-mount the DataTable :
 $('my-table').DataTable();
```

And it doesn't update, it double a line already existing or display the line I inserted until I change the current page.

What's even more weird is that if I do :

```
  $('my-table').DataTable().destroy();
  // Here I'm getting the data and put it in the Vue instance
```

So now it's a simple HTML table on my page, correctly updated with Vue, I type in the console :

`$('my-table').DataTable()`

And it works just fine. I don't understand because it's exactly the same as above except that i'm typing it from the console right ?

I hope that it's clear enough. Thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue might be competing for DOM elements here with DataTable.

If you use `$('my-table').DataTable()` it references the table by the DOM position.

When working with Vue, it's better to use `$ref` to reference an element.

Vue does some magic in the background that allows only object that changed to re-render. So it seems like when you're destroying and creating a new object, Vue doesn't have a way to know that it changed, and doesn't re-render it.

there's a few ways you might for you.

- use a key for the DataTable element. When there's a change update the key, which will redraw the element
- you can try `this.$forceUpdate();` at the end of the function
- you can also try `this.$nextTick().then(()=>$('my-table').DataTable())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use `$this.$forceUpdate();` but it doesn't change anything. How can I update the key of my DataTable element ? I actually use one but once I destroy it, I must re-use the DOM element to target it right ?

Comment: her's an answer to a related question regarding keys and remounting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459837/how-to-re-mount-a-component/47466574#47466574

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I just tried this and it works perfectly! :)