# how to re-mount a child component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

im searching how to re-mount a child component. Not just re-render it, but totally re-mount (so  `mounted()`  function of my child component will be called.

I know there already is a similar question ([How to re-mount a component in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459837/how-to-re-mount-a-component-in-vuejs)), but the author was searching how to re-rendre (and the solution match this case), when i follow these instructions, my  `mounted()`  function is not called.

here is what i have:

I have a page with 2 component:

- an upload component
- a list component

here is what i want:

I use my upload component to upload a .zip file to my api. Then, the API parse the .zip, and store its information in database.
My list il a table of every .zip, displaying basic informations (name, description...), taking data from the store, and if empty, using axios to fetch from API (everything into the `mounted()` hook).
the only solution i have to update the list when i upload a new .zip is to fetch the list from my API.

here is the problem: i cant find a way to update my list. Knowing data are fetched when my list component is mounted, the solution would be to re-mount my component, But I can't find how, so I'm asking you guys.

here is my page code:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center mr-auto">
        <card>
          <Upload @upload="upload" ></Upload>
        </card>
      </div>
    <div>
      <List :ProjID="selectedProject.id" :key="childKey"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import upload from "./upload.vue";
import API from "./services/API";
import list from "./list.vue";

export default {
  name: "ProjectCard",
  components: {
    Upload,
    List,
  },
  props: {
    selectedProject: null
  },
  data() {
    return {
      childKey: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    upload(file) {
      API.postJob(file, this.selectedProject.id)// <-- function calling axios, everything is working here. It also delete stored file in my store, so the list component will fetch from API to get new data
        .then(response => {
          this.childKey += 1;
          console.log("success!")
        })
        .catch(response => {
            console.log("not succes :c")
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

here is my list mounted() hook:

```
  async mounted() {
    const fetch = await API.getAll(); <-- this function fetch from my store, and if nothing comes out, fetch from API.
    if (fetch == 401) {
      console.log("not logged in");
    }
    if (fetch == 500) {
      console.log("error");
      return();
    }
    this.fetchedFiles = fetch;
    this.dataReady = true;
  }
```

I have to re-call the mounted() hook in order to update my list (or any better solution)

Comment: Linked question is about recreating/mounting component and should work for you

Comment: So until you add more details and code, I'm voting to close this as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459837/how-to-re-mount-a-component-in-vuejs

Comment: I added a bunch of information, tell me if you need more details

Comment: abstract all the code which is in the mounted and put it in a method, then you can call it in mounted and after upload. btw if you use async/await you should also use try/catch and return is not a function.

Comment: Except the `return();` I don't see anything wrong with the code and still think changing the `key` should work. Can you put `console.log` at the very beginning of `mounted` hook to rule out the possibility problem is in `API.getAll` method?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, I had another problem that i figured out myself: The data in store were'nt deleted correctly. Solving this and using your solution solved my problem, thanks!

for the asyn/await, the function that i call (API.getAll, i call axios, and then use .then().catch

and for the return, it was not an error in code, but an error i did when i shared the code with you.

thanks!